# Is it possible to fill zeroes in Mongodb's map reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map reduce that is grouping by date:

```
map = %Q{
  function() {
    var rounded_time = this.created_at;
    rounded_time.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    emit(rounded_time.getTime() / 1000, this.total);
  }
}

reduce = %Q{
  function(key, values) {
    var result = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value) {
      result += value;
    });
    return result;
  }
}

data = Order.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
```

But of course some dates don't have any orders, so they don't appear in the result.  This is being fed into a time series graph so it would be nice to have zeroes on those days.

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to fill in the missing dates with zeros.  It seems like doing an initial `emit(time, 0)` on each date would be one way but I haven't seen a way to do that in mongo.

So I'm stuck massaging the data after it comes out of the map reduce which is not quite as efficient and prone to rounding errors.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this issue? I'm facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best done when you go to form the reports.

The problem is those rows do not exist and the MR cannot actually form new documents at will in a loop, it can only modify what documents are inputted to it.

So when you iterate the documents in the graph you, most likely, know what deliminator you use for the time series you are searching for (day, month, year) and can easily modify your data to add 0 values at these points which are missing. Normnally the best way is not to scroll the cursor in the loop to make the graph but instead to scroll your list of dates and then grab that date from the cursor or put a zero value there.

> So I'm stuck massaging the data after it comes out of the map reduce which is not quite as efficient and prone to rounding errors

It shouldn't be prone to errors, it should be, if done right, as accurate as the database since you are using a client defined (I assume) time range and you are grouping on deliminators so it shouldn't be error prone.

Comment: The part that is brittle is the timestamps are ints.  If you try to group by day or hour, you get sparse timestamps.  It's error prone to loop through these and try to hit the ints right on the head (with timezones changing any everything).  I ended up calling `toDateString()` on the Javascript dates to get it into something that was impossible to mess up.  But I still haven't found an elegant way to get the zeroes on all days up front.  I'm stuck iterating through the data after the map reduce, which doesn't feel super efficient, but works.  Anyway, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You solve that by making standardised timings, i.e. you make all int timestamps start from the 0 hour UTC of the day and then change the timezone after to match, so you always query in a standard time never in the users time and never in like hour 2 of the day. This is the way most people do stats sanely. There are a couple of links out there for how to do stats in MongoDB, a quick google search will bring them up